# HTML5 required="" attribute with .NET webforms

Tags: .net, html, webforms

I'm trying to use the new `required` attribute on form fields in my .NET 4.5 webforms application.

However, since there is only one `<form>` surrounding all the controls on the page (webforms style), the browser does not know which fields to be validated when a submit button is pressed.

A stripped version of a page with both login functionality and a page search is attached below.

When I click the Search button my browser tell me that i have to fill in the username and password fields first. And when I try to login it tells me I have to enter some text in the search field. Because all of the fields are children of the same `<form>` tag.

Any one else had this problem or came up with a solution? I would like to use the HTML5 attributes for form validation, no javascript solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" runat="server" id="mainform">


    <%// Search %>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="searchButton" >

      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="searchQuery" ClientIDMode="Static" required="required" />
      <asp:Button runat="server" ID="searchButton" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Search"/>

    </asp:Panel>


    <%// Login %>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="signInButton">

      <label for="inputusername">Username</label>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="inputusername" required="required" />

      <label for="inputpassword">Password</label>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Password" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="inputpassword" required="required" />

      <asp:Button ID="signInButton" runat="server" />

    </asp:Panel>

  </form>
</body>
</html>

</html>
```

Comment: do you tried to put out the form the search ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand that...

Comment: Have you tried to search outside the form?

Comment: Can't do that. The form tag has to wrap all the server controls...

Comment: The HTML5 `required` attribute does not allow setup by any group, and ASP.NET does not (without tomfoolery) allow multiple `form` tags (with server controls). You could instead use `RequiredFieldValidator` and set the `ValidationGroup` properties of the associated controls.

Comment: So it can't be done. Well in that case I can at least stop looking for a solution :) Thanks Mike.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since the ASP.Net Web Forms programming model does not allow multiple HTML  tags, this is something you cannot take advantage of.

Comment: See the second answer

Answer (score 5):

Try this please.. It worked for me..

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" 
             ClientIDMode="Static" 
             ID="inputusername"                    
             required />
```

Comment: Is the duplicate `ClientIDMode="Static"` intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Add novalidate attribute to the Search button. It's that easy.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp